# There is a 2006 error( server gone away) continously in my django, why is it?

Tags: mysql, django, connection

I don't set the variable CONN_MAX_AGE in my config, it is said it will be 0 as default, which means every request will reopen a new connection.But In my program it continuously shows the error (2006, server gone away) as every query starts.I don't know why.

Comment: You need to be a bit more specific.  Is this when loading a page through a view?  Running a management command?  Is it every view, or just some - are you uploading large files, for example?

Comment: I run my program in the command mode, and my program will last about 5hours, which continously sends query to the db.At the end of my program, it continously reports the error.But my config is set as above. I am looking forward for your answer. @Withnail

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You're not alone.  This has been a known problem since 1.6, and I believe remains.  (Happy to be corrected).  Original documentation relating to the problem [from the Django Project.](https://code.djangoproject.com/ticket/21597#comment:30)

Broadly, I would reconfigure your problem so that you're opening a new database connection periodically.   We have a number of long-running processes that connect to MySQL and found this to be a recurrent issue.

You have three options.

Break your function up slightly so that the chunks can each establish their own connection.  This should be the implicit behaviour from the set-up you've described, but I've also run into problems with it.

from django import db

```
for thing in some_data:
    db.connections.close_all()
    your_stuff_here()
```

The explicit closing (and subsequent reopening) of the connection is also clearer than the implicit behaviour, which is also dependent on how your MySQL timeout is configured.

A very hacky workaround is to wrap your internal functions in a try/except:

```
from django.db.utils import OperationalError
try: 
   stuff = Stuff.objects.get(id=123456)
except OperationalError:
   from django.db import connections
   c = connections['default'].cursor() 
   stuff = Stuff.objects.get(id=123456)
```

This definitely works, as the cursor connection reopens it in the event of a failure.  Although I implemented this as a fix on one of our long running processes, it's definitely a hack.  I don't recommend it, and we subsequently refactored it out to the first method.

Lastly, you could up your MySQL timeout, which is noted on the django documentation page as a less-optimal solution.

https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.6/en/auto-reconnect.html

Comment: thanks very much ,i think the CONN_MAX_AGE is useless, I have set it to different values, but it remains the same connection as I see from the mysql processlist.

Comment: CONN_MAX_AGE is only used in HTTP requests where Django handles it using signals. so if you're running management command you'll need to explicitly call close_old_connections so it will check the time when it needs to close. correct me if i'm wrong.